# Limit paginated result set to a maximum number of posts

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I would like to create a paginated result using a maximum number of posts. I have been trying to achieve this using `\WP_Query` class e.g:

```
function getQuery(int $page, int $posts_per_page = 2, int $max_posts = 7): \WP_Query
{
  $args = [
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'numberposts' => $max_posts,
    'offset' => $page - 1,
    'post_status' => [
      'publish',
    ],
  ];
  return new \WP_Query($args);
}

// Get the last page query which I would assume only would contain a single post.
$query = getQuery(3);
```

This almost works, the problem is the maximum number of posts when using a paginated result set. I would assume that the last page only would get a single post taking the `numberposts` argument in to consideration, but this does not seem to work.

One solution is to check if we have reached the end and then slice of the extra returned posts from the array e.g:

```
if (($page + 1) * $posts_per_page > $max_posts) {
  $count = $max_posts - ($page * $posts_per_page);
  $query->posts = array_slice($query->posts, 0, $count);
  $query->found_posts = $count;
  $query->post_count = $count;
}
```

but this not seems like a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand this correctly. Below is an approach using few hooks to modify the query before fetching the data. Might need some adjustments and testing.

Note that `numberposts` is just an alias for `posts_per_page` in `get_posts()` wrapper of `WP_Query`.

We could try to use `paged` instead of `offset`, but it will not work if we plan to modify `posts_per_page` on the last page calculated by `ceil($max_posts/$posts_per_page )`. So we set `offset` directly as:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
  'offset'         => ($page - 1) * $posts_per_page,
  'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
);
```

We can adjust the number of found posts if it exceeds `$max_posts`:

```
$fn_found_posts = function( $found_posts, $q ) use ( $max_posts, $page ) { 
    return $found_posts > $max_posts ? $max_posts : $found_posts;
};

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', $fn_pre_get_posts );
```

but this filtering will not adjust the returned posts array.

We can therefore adjust the `posts_per_page` to `$max_posts - ($page - 1) * $posts_per_page` for the last page (according to `$max_posts`) because that will adjust the previously set `offset`:

```
$fn_pre_get_posts = function( $q ) use ($page, $posts_per_page, $max_posts ) {  
    if ( $page == ceil($max_posts/$posts_per_page ) ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $max_posts - ($page - 1) * $posts_per_page );
    }
};

add_filter( 'found_posts', $fn_found_posts );
```

We can then return empty array for pages after the last page (according to `$max_posts`):

```
$fn_posts_pre_query = function( $posts ) use ($page, $posts_per_page, $max_posts ) { 
    return $page > ceil( $max_posts/$posts_per_page) ? array() : $posts; 
};

add_filter( 'posts_pre_query', $fn_posts_pre_query );
```

Here the modified `getQuery()` function:

```
function getQuery(int $page, int $posts_per_page = 2, int $max_posts = 7): \WP_Query {
    $fn_found_posts = function( $found_posts ) use ( $max_posts ) { 
        return $found_posts > $max_posts ? $max_posts : $found_posts;
    };

    $fn_posts_pre_query = function( $posts ) use ($page, $posts_per_page, $max_posts ) { 
        return $page > ceil($max_posts/$posts_per_page) ? array() : $posts; 
    };
    
    $fn_pre_get_posts = function( $q ) use ($page, $posts_per_page, $max_posts ) {  
        if ( $page == ceil($max_posts/$posts_per_page ) ) {
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $max_posts - ($page - 1) * $posts_per_page );
        }
    };
    
    add_filter( 'found_posts', $fn_found_posts );
    add_filter( 'posts_pre_query', $fn_posts_pre_query );
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', $fn_pre_get_posts );

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'offset'         => ($page - 1) * $posts_per_page,
        'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
    );
    $q = new \WP_Query($args);

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', $fn_pre_get_posts );
    remove_filter( 'posts_pre_query', $fn_empty_array );
    remove_filter( 'found_posts', $fn_found_posts );

    return $q;
}
```

ps: one might add some input range checks etc.

Comment: I will test around with the above as soon as I have a little more time, thank you.

Comment: @Cyclonecode hopefully it worked out for you.